# best open source IDE to work with EXTJS

Tags: ide, extjs4, development-environment

I want to develop a web app in EXTJS 4.0, but I'm not sure about which IDE to use. I'm looking for open source IDE with its pros and cons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific IDE for ExtJS. Since it is a javascript framework you can use text editors with additional plugins to use features like syntax highlighting, code formatting etc. [webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) seems to be more promissing one in javascript world but it is not a free tool. Here are some of the popular tools people use to write javascript code.

- [Komodo](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/)(Text editor is free but IDE is paid one)
- [Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081)
- [Sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/)
- [Spket](http://www.spket.com/)(Text editor is free but IDE is paid one) ... many more.

Personally I would prefer eclipse with [spket eclipse](http://javadevtool.blogspot.in/2014/05/spket-eclipse-plugin.html) plugin through which you can use formatting/validation/code completion features. (Only default features are available in free one, to customize these features one should move to spket paid version). My second choice would be notepad++ with additional plugins.